# Displaying a list of files that have changed since last changeset in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I work with a team, and we use Subversion.

In the morning I want to see exactly what was changed since the last build, is there a way to get a list of files that were modified between changesets?

**Update**
Using tortoiseSVN please

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With TortoiseSVN: rightclick, pick *TortoiseSVN*->*Show log*.

You'll get a list of revisions and can pick any two to compare.

Answer (score 18):

This has been long ago, but to precisely answer the original question, i.e. "is there a way to get a list of files that were modified between changesets in TortoiseSVN", here is a way to achieve that:

1. On top-level folder, right-click and TortoiseSVN --> Show log.
2. From the list of revisions, select **all** back to, but not including, the last revision that you want to compare against
3. Right-click on the selections and chose Compare revisions
4. Now you're looking at a list of all modified files since that particular revision

Original article: http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/How-to-export-only-files-modified-since-revision-x-with-TortoiseSVN.aspx

Comment: This is great! I just wish Tortoise provided more options to sort by.

Comment: UPDATE: In current TortoiseSVN, it is NOT necessary to select all the files in between.  You can simply click on one revision, then ctrl-click on the other revision (so the two are selected), then rt-click on either one, do "Compare revisions".  This WILL show all changes between those two revisions, including changes made in any intervening revision. (Useful tip: Once in that compare dialog, you can click on either  one, to change to a different revision for comparison.)

Answer (score 12):

Usually `svn` outputs exactly that list when you do an `update`.

`svn diff` has a `--summarize` option, too:

```
svn diff -rPREV:HEAD --summarize
svn diff -r10374:11128 --summarize
```

You'll get the idea :-)

Answer (score 6):

The `-u` option to `svn status` shows which files have been changed on the server since the last time you did an update. This can be useful to get a preview of what's about to change for you, before you do an `svn update`.

Answer (score 1):

- `svn st -u` gives a screen shot of all changed files.
- `svn diff` returns differences between working copy and the last committed revision; diff works over single files or folders or everything.
- `svn update` doesn't change differences and status of your changed files.
- `svn revert` rolls back your changes to the last rev.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using TortoiseSVN you can make it show the *Check For Modifications* dialog, from a batch file, like this:

```
@echo off
tortoiseproc /command:repostatus /path:"c:\some_path\wc"
```

I assume you're only interested in what's changed since your last update. If you're interested in what's changed between two specific revisions then you can make it show the *Log Messages* window, like this:

```
@echo off
tortoiseproc /command:log /path:"c:\some_path\wc"
```

For more info about the tortoiseproc commands, see [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html).

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend [CommitMonitor](https://tools.stefankueng.com/CommitMonitor.html) - also from the dev(s) who brought you TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Update - Note that TortoiseSVN 1.9 and later has a project monitor included, which has similar features as the CommitMonitor. (from the site)

Answer (score 0):

`svn status` will show what's been changed since the last commit or update. i think you can also use it with -r, or like `svn status -r rev1:rev2`

Comment: No, you can't: Subcommand 'status' doesn't accept option '-r [--revision] ARG' (at least not svn 1.6.1 on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

```
svnlook changed /path/to/repos
```

will give you everything that happened in the last commit.